# Adding a xkill icon in gnome-shell's dock

Tags: gnome, dock, xkill

First of all, sorry for my English.

I'm trying to add an icon in the gnome-shell's dock (with Ubuntu 13.04 and 13.10) for the command line app `xkill`, but it doesn't work, since it is a terminal application. But if I create the menu entry as a "terminal application" (writting it in a .desktop file or throghout the "Main Menu" application), it opens, consequently, a terminal with the message: "Select the window bla bla bla....".

What I really want is a more natural and direct way for closing a blocked window by force, and not by means of a terminal.

For older versions of gnome-shell there was a little extension which made it (adding a little icon in the top bar), but it exists no longer (or I haven't found it).

Solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Create a launcher with the command `gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop` as suggested by @maythux, but just add `/usr/bin/xkill` as the command.
(Do *NOT* use `gnome-terminal -e`).

This creates the launcher on the desktop.

Simply drag it to the dock and remove it from the desktop if you like.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use Easystroke Gesture Recognition for that purpose. Install it then pick up Gesture Button >button 3 from preferences tab, it lets you run commands dragging right button and drawing a figure like line, circle or whatever you like then switch to Action tab and record a guesture dragging right button, finally add commad

sudo xkill

that's all.

Whenever you want to kill a frozen window, just drag right button and draw the shape you attained, you will get a x shape cursor to kill the window.

Comment: Thanks, it seems a good solution, but this application doesn't recognize propertly my new gesture. It doesn't matter what type of "shape" I make with my touchpad: I have tried with the Shift key plus the touchpad right button, making a circle, but after doing it, the application continues waiting for my gesture. Only when I make a last click over the message window the gesture is recognize, but the thing recognized is just this last click.

Comment: You don't need modifier keys such as shift, alt. Did I miss a step to mention? You must click add action in Action tab then record a gesture

Answer (score 1):

You can do this trick to get your need(it still use the terminal but you have not to take care about.)

First create a launcher on desktop by using the old GUI dialog.

Using `ALT+F2` type:

`gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop`

This will start the dialog( Create launcher):

[image]

In the Name field put any name you like.

In the command field put the command `gnome-terminal -e "xkill"` or if you have other terminal emulators you can use like `xterm` or whatever.

Now drag and drop the created launcher to the Unity launcher and try it :).

---

Another Solution:

[Here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/force-quit-applet-unity-launcher/) is a scipt to do what you like and they have a unity launcher and you can learn how to install and use

Comment: Same problem. It opens a terminal window, and I don't want it.

Comment: but you have not to think about it will be close by the time you click on what you want to close

Comment: Ah, you're right. But, is it possible to avoid this "terminal window"?, all of this is for my father and he has no knowledge about "terminals". I prefer he don't see that window.

Comment: @Peregring-lk I don't think you can get rid of.anyway you must keep in mind terminal are Linux soul